# Storyboard in Xcode generates unwanted fixedFrame="YES" for all views in a controller

Tags: xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I'm using Git for source control, and it has enabled me to pinpoint exactly why one of my view refuses to position itself correctly. Turns out every view in a single controller has been set to be fixed by the `fixedFrame="YES"` XML property. I isolated this change from the commit it was written in, and it is now in my working directory. But here's the annoying part. 
I can revert the Storyboard file and properly, the XML will remove all the `fixedFrame` attributes. But as soon as I start make a new build for my test devices, the changes are re-applied before compilation, and all the views are set to a fixed width. It's driving me nuts.

I've deleted the derived data, incessantly cleaned the project file, restarted Xcode and my development machine.

I thought maybe the `fixedWidth` XML attribute was correlated to the `Autoresize Subviews` IB option, but toggling that has no effect on the generation of the fixed frame stuff. I figure there must be something unexpected in a meta-workspace-data kind of folder.

Really could use some extra help, I've searched for everything I can think of regarding this, and there seems to be no resolution in sight.

Comment: What change did you make to get it set in the first place? I don't use IB much but doesn't the fixed frame get set if you don't have enough constraints to define your layout fully? It just takes them from the sizes in IB? What happens if you "add suggested constraints" from the Autolayout issues menu?

Comment: That's exactly what happened- turns out all of my constraints were removed in the entire Storyboard. Somehow I inadvertently deleted every single one. Which is strange, because I'm aware of the "remove all constraints in view" option, but not one to remove the entire Storyboard's. But thanks for the input, you were right on the money.

Comment: Glad to help. It might have happened if the use autolayout box was checked then unchecked?

Comment: I'd bet that's exactly what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if anyone will run across this problem the same way I did- but the answer is that all my constraints were removed for that Storyboard by some accident and without constraints, the `fixedFrame` property is automatically set when the Storyboard is generated.

Solution : Trash the commit that caused this, or layout everything manually again.

Answer (score 2):

You can go in and discard the fixedFrame hunks...

[image: Storyboard fixedFrame]

Or I have also found that cleaning, deleting derived data, and restarting Xcode can resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happens when enabling/disabling Size Classes.

[image]

I think this should be unchecked by default as you tend to create "variants" of your layout when inadvertently changing the current class and then modifying any interface element.

[image]

I was changing it a lot because the usual Assistant Editor Preview seems to be unavailable randomly.

In sum, I now avoid using classes for as long as I can. Once the base layout is done I can enable it to make final adjustments for different screen sizes. That is if auto layout constraints were not enough.